# Razor Runtime Compilation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor

ive been having trouble trying to install razor runtime compilation and i continue to get a fault. i updated the vs2019 community edition and was able to click on the checkbox to add the "runtime compilation". when the project is loading, it doesnt install the "razor runtime compliation" package. it doesnt allow me to search for it via NuGet anymore either.

I tried my best to search around and some made it seem very simple to just install it from the pack manager or NuGet. Im using asp.net core 3.1 and vs2019 16.6.1 community edition.

EDIT: HOW CAN I INSTALL ...razor.runtimecompilation.i have not been able to figure out a solution to the error.

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: i just edit my post but, im trying to install the razor.runtimecompilation and cant figure out how to install it. ive been stuck on this error from the image i shared for a while. the image is showing the install button but, its not installing the package. instead its giving an error while trying to restore nuget packages.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You got an error and posted a picture of it.  I don't read images.  Hope someone else does.

Comment: my errors is saying "error occured while restoring Nuget packages: failed to retrieve information about 'microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.runtimecompilation'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"

This package is from nuget.org in my visual studio. While from your screenshot, it retrive from http://packagesource. Maybe you should configure your package source:

[image]